# Why is the Getter called on Dictionary initialization?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
var dataRow = new FlatDataRow
{
    Id = 12,
    Fields = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "skills", skills}
    }
};
```

which works.
The following doesn't, though:

```
var dataRow = new FlatDataRow
{
    Id = 12,
    Fields = 
    {
        { "skills", skills}
    }
};
```

I receive a NullReferenceException. The only difference is the "new Dict..:". `Fields` is a standard `get;set;` -Property.

Why is the Getter from `Fields` (which causes the error) even called when I use the second declaration?

(`skills` is a of type `List<object>`)

Comment: Because that's what that syntax means.

Comment: Note that it would be perfectly possible for the parameterless `FlatDataRow` constructor to have initialised its own `Fields` property to a non-null value (and possibly not even provide a setter) and then the second example would work exactly as you would want it it.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers for the minimum requirements of a collection initializer

Comment: @TimSchmelter the nested thing is a collection initializer and not an object initializer or a collection constructor with initializer. The Problem is, that `Field.Add(...)` is called on the null field, not that `Field.SomeProperty` is assigned. So yes, the object initializer tries to work on a null object, but the kind of work here is collection specific :)